# how to create a stateless service at runtime on local service fabric server

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I'm trying to create instances of stateless services on demand at runtime without additonal entries about types at manifest file.

At the begging I thought, that I can use

```
using (FabricRuntime fabricRuntime = FabricRuntime.Create())
      {
          fabricRuntime.RegisterServiceType("ServiceType", typeof(Service));
      }
```

and

```
ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync("ServiceType", context => new Service(context)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Howerver I still have to register service type or service template at manifest file, but that's beside the point.

Now, I wonder if it is possible to create instance of stateless service without metadata at manifest or powershell scripts? Just write services programmatically?

Comment: I think you can use FabricClient.ServiceManager for this, but I don't remember the proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can, if you use the [Docker compose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-docker-compose) approach. Create containers, instead of Service Fabric applications.

Use the [REST api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/sfclient-v60-index-compose-deployment) to deploy dynamically generated docker-compose.yml files to create instances.